# What's a good word for "offer", as in "...for offering us eternal life..."?

Tags: words

I'm trying to translate a sentence that includes the following phrase:

> ...for offering us eternal life...

Finding a good word for "offer" is apparently a little easier said that done.  jisho.org does say that there's always オファーする, but that seems like a last resort to me.  They don't even mark it as a commonly used word.

That's not to say I haven't found some "commonly used words" for "offer"; jisho.org has many listed.  The problem is that they all have alternate meanings and/or fairly specific contexts in which they're used.

I tried running a search for the word "offer" in the Bible, but I'm reluctant to go with the Japanese word used in verses having to do with sacrifices, and in other verses, the Japanese translation I have seems to sort of dodge use of the word "offer".

I don't want to use a word that is inappropriate in this context, and I am *especially* trying to avoid using a word for "offer" that has other, equally applicable meanings.  (This weeds out the prase 提供する, for example, because in this context, it could imply that we don't have to accept eternal life to receive it.)  So what's a good word?

**EDIT**

Here's the whole sentence:

> Lord, we thank You for all the blessings which You give us everyday, especially for what You did for us on the cross and for offering us eternal life through Your Son Jesus Christ.

Comment: If you include the whole sentence for some context, it might help more.

Comment: For things like this in the future, a bilingual Bible would likely be an invaluable resource.

Comment: I'm not trying to be pretentious, at all. Don't know what you are working on. But, you should say "every day" (two words), not "everyday". "Everyday" is just an adjective.

Comment: @rintaun I tried to use one here, but the Japanese translation would kind of get around using the word "offer" in verses that weren't related to sacrifices or such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a Christian who worked at a Christian church in Japan for two years, I can say this would definitely be translated with 与える; more specifically, 与えてくださる.  The whole sentence would be something like

> 主よ、日々の祝福、そしてまた、十字架の[御業]{み・わざ}によってイエスキリストを通して永遠の命を**与えてくださり**、（本当に）感謝します。

Comment: Thanks, istrasci!  So if 与える is used, folks would understand that to mean "offer", instead of "give"?  I just want to make sure somebody doesn't take it to mean that we don't have to ask Jesus for salvation.

Comment: Not necessarily, but that comes down to more of the Japanese' general lack of understanding of Biblical Christianity, and explaining it (that we need to ask) through evangelism.  If this was part of an "alter call" prayer, then "offer" might better be translated as 申し出る or 差し出す, then followed up by the explanation.  But if it's part of a "normal" thanksgiving prayer, then it would definitely be 与える.  I'll edit my answer later to include this.

Comment: It's for offeratory prayer.